# How to activate compiler options to support SIMD instructions

Tags: compiler-construction, g++

I have a matrix matrix multiplication program in c++, does any body know how to active
compiler options to support SIMD instructions?

Comment: I use g++ compiler 4.6.3

Comment: @damienfrancoisI use g++ compiler 4.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want to use Intel/AMD SIMD instructions, and are looking for `-mfpmath=sse`, `-msse`, `-msse2`, etc. flags, documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html#i386-and-x86-64-Options).